# How to use type synonyms with algebraic data type?

Tags: haskell, types

For the following code, how do I specify which phone number type (HomePhone or WorkPhone) the function storePhone is storing the Int as?

```
type HomePhone = Int
type WorkPhone = Int

data Phone = HomePhone
           | WorkPhone

storePhone :: int -> Phone 
storePhone num = num

main :: IO ()
main = print $ storePhone 12345678
```

This question was a simplified version of the question I have for a side project I'm doing.
I have a module that parses a file to the relevant data type (aka like in sample the Phone type).  All the data is Double but have different semantic meaning.  In another module, I have methods that use the data.  Each method takes different permutations of data types(aka HomePhone, WorkPhone) as arguments.  I could have made HomePhone and WorkPhone data type or even newtype, but it would have made the methods that used the data look messy with lots of pattern matching and stuff.  So was just wondering if I could simplify the data type(aka Phone) so that it was a bit more elegant and still type safe.  Cheers!
I guess I should do the following?

```
type HomePhone = Int
type WorkPhone = Int

data Phone = HomePhone HomePhone 
           | WorkPhone WorkPhone
```

Comment: Does it even compile? Compiler can give you a lot of helpful information in errors and warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In its current form the `Phone` type isn't capable of storing any phone numbers. It has two constructors that both take zero arguments and thus can't store anything. The fact that the constructors' names are equal to the type names you defined earlier doesn't mean anything.

You probably intended something like this:

```
type PhoneNumber = String -- Storing phone numbers as ints is a bad idea

data PhoneType = HomePhone
               | WorkPhone
                 deriving Show

data Phone = Phone PhoneType PhoneNumber
             deriving Show

storePhone :: PhoneNumber -> PhoneType -> Phone
storePhone number typ = Phone typ number

main :: IO ()
main = print $ storePhone "12345678" HomePhone
```

Answer (score 4):

I think sepp2k answered your question very well, but I will try to explain, why I think you had the problem in the first place. There is a difference between types and values - and between type constructors and value constructors.

```
Phone = Phone
```

In this example, the left hand side is a type, and the right hand side is a value. Notice that a type and a value can both have the same name. The compiler will figure out, what you mean. Basically, in type declarations and data declarations, you mean the type, and in function implementations, you mean the value.

```
Phone = NoPhone
      | Phone Int
```

In this example, `NoPhone` is a value, and the right hand side `Phone` is a value constructor, since it takes a value of type `Int` to make a value. The left hand side is still a type.

```
Container a = NotEmpty a
            | Empty
```

In this example, `Container` is a type constructor, since you can give it a type such a `Int` to get a type - which in this case would be the type `Container Int`. `Empty` is a value, and `NotEmpty` is a value constructor, that takes a value of whatever type you happen to pick for `a` - let's call that type `T`, to yield a value of type `Container T`.

In your example, you mix the concepts of types and values.

```
type HomePhone = Int
type WorkPhone = Int
```

This says that `HomePhone` and `WorkPhone` are just different names for the type `Int`

```
data Phone = HomePhone
           | WorkPhone
```

This says that anything of type `Phone` has either the value `HomePhone` or the value `WorkPhone`. Importantly, these values are not the same as the type synonyms with the same names, which you declared earlier.

```
storePhone :: int -> Phone
```

This says that storePhone takes a value of type `Int` and returns a value of type `Phone`.

```
storePhone num = num
```

This is a problem. In this line, num is a value of type `Int`, but you return num, and you just said in the type declaration that you would return a value of type `Phone`, i.e. either the value `HomePhone` or the value `WorkPhone`. If you wanted to be silly, but conform to your type declaration, you could do

```
storePhone num = if num > 0 then HomePhone else WorkPhone -- silly, but compiles :)
```